# How can I enter data into a new column based on the value of another column in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large data frame with campaign finance data - the data frame has a column for the candidate's committee name, but not one for the candidates name.

How can I add a new column for the candidates name automatically based on the committee name? I want the code to read the committee name in each row, and then assign the appropriate candidate name.

Comment: Maybe a `merge` will help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a one to one mapping between committee name and candidate name, which you can describe in a dictionary, you would just need to use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function.

Example Code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data  = pd.DataFrame([["A"], ["B"], ["A"], ["C"]], columns=["Committee Name"])
>>> data
  Committee Name
0              A
1              B
2              A
3              C
>>> committee_name_mapping = {"A": "AName", "B": "BName", "C": "CName"}
>>> data["Candidate Name"] = data["Committee Name"].map(committee_name_mapping)
>>> data
  Committee Name Candidate Name
0              A          AName
1              B          BName
2              A          AName
3              C          CName
```

Comment: Creating a map is probably the best way to do this